# how can I enable the junit 5 unicode theme using gradle?

Tags: gradle, junit5, gradle-kotlin-dsl

> When using the ConsoleLauncher with the unicode theme enabled, execution of RepeatedTestsDemo results in the following output to the console.

```
├─ RepeatedTestsDemo ✔
│  ├─ repeatedTest() ✔
│  │  ├─ repetition 1 of 10 ✔
```

how can I enable the unicode theme using gradle with kotlin configuration?

Comment: How do you currently use the ConsoleLauncher from gradle?

Comment: I don't, that's why I'm asking how to do this

Comment: From what I found it seems you need to download a JAR file, then pass the `--details-theme=unicode` option to it. This can be done with a gradle Exec task, but I'll leave that to you.